# Understanding interpolation method in javafx

Tags: java, animation, javafx, interpolation

I'm trying to create an animation in JavaFX.

I'm having difficulty understanding a method though.

Can anyone explain what exactly the interpolate method at the bottom does?

More specifically, how does it use the modulus?

```
import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.animation.Transition;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class SpriteAnimation extends Transition {

    private  ImageView imageView;

    private  int count;            
    private  int columns;         
    private  int offsetX;         
    private  int offsetY;         
    private  int width;            
    private  int height;          
    private int lastIndex;

    public SpriteAnimation(
            ImageView imageView, 
            Duration duration, 
            int count,   int columns,
            int offsetX, int offsetY,
            int width,   int height) {

        this.imageView = imageView;       
        this.count     = count;       
        this.columns   = columns;
        this.offsetX   = offsetX;       
        this.offsetY   = offsetY;
        this.width     = width;
        this.height    = height;

        setCycleDuration(duration);  
        setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR); 
    }

    protected void interpolate(double k) {
        // 
        int index = Math.min((int) Math.floor(k * count), count - 1);
        if (index != lastIndex) {

            int x = (index % columns) * width  + offsetX;
            int y = (index / columns) * height + offsetY;
            imageView.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(x, y, width, height));

            lastIndex = index;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When the transition runs different values for `k` will be passed to the `interpolate`. At the beginning of the animation `0.0` will be passed for `k` and at the end of the animation `1.0` will be passed.

```
int index = Math.min((int) Math.floor(k * count), count - 1);
```

Calculates the `index` in the range `0` to `count-1`. BTW: I'd prefer `(int) (k * count)` to `(int) Math.floor(k * count)`, since a cast to `int` truncates the floating point value anyways.

On a change of the index the part of the image the `ImageView` should display is modified to show the appropriate part of the image. Here you iterate through the sprites line by line from left to right.

```
index % columns
```

is the rest of the division of `index` by `columns`. This means for every increment of `index` by one the result will increase by 1 until `columns` is reached; in that case it starts over at 0 instead.

Because of this property, it can be used to determine the horizontal position of image to be displayed. You just have to multiply with the width of a sprite to get the x coordinates of the left.

```
index / columns
```

is the division of `index` by `columns` without rest, i.e. `index / columns` and `(index - index % columns) / columns` result in the same value. The result increases by 1 for every `columns` you add to `index`; it increases by 1 when `index % column` starts over at `0`. Therefore it can be used to determine the y coordinate of the sprite; You just have multiply by the height of a sprite.

Examples for `columns = 3`

```
index   |   index % 3  |   index / 3
--------------------------------------
  0     |     0        |     0
  1     |     1        |     0
  2     |     2        |     0
  3     |     0        |     1
  4     |     1        |     1
  5     |     2        |     1
  6     |     0        |     2
             ...
 31     |     1        |     10
```

This way you iterate through sprites in the following order

```
-------------------
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
-------------------
|  4  |  5  |  6  |
-------------------
        ...
-------------------
| 31  | 32  |     |
-------------------
```